# How to convert View into Imageview in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, view, casting, imageview

```
fun tap(view: View) {

    val img = view
 }
```

I want this variable img to be an Image view, but Idk how to convert view into imageview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your view like this:

```
val img: ImageView = view as ImageView
```

The "as" keyword is going to convert the view.

Welcome to stackoverflow!!

Comment: its better to use as? operator to avoid null pointer exception, you can check my answer below to see  its execution.

Answer (score 6):

Please try casting as below:

```
val img: ImageView = view as ImageView
```

Answer (score 2):

If in case the view in your function can take multiple values, in that case you might want to first check if the view corresponds to the expected values using the following code:-

```
if(view is ImageView) { //do Something}

else if(view is TextView) { //do something}
```

Otherwise how to cast a view in kotlin?
As other answers also mentioned, use the `as?` keyword, which will cast to the type if it is successful, or return null if the cast is unsuccessful as shown below in case of string, :-

```
private fun castOrNull(anything: Any): String? {
return anything as? String  }
```

check the here for [reference](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-made-casting-so-much-neater-657c165c4858).